# sorting table rows and passing the sort index via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vT67Q/

the table looks like this:

```
table_products
----------------
id
sort_order
product_name
view_count
model_num
price
shipp_sep
```

this table contains over 100 products and each product is associated to a category. they dont have a sort_order value the field for each is null. My question is how do i pass the sort index? would i have jquery count every row and append a value to it into the hidden textbox? or how would it be done without having sort values colliding and always staying unique and in order.

Comment: what do you mean by "sort index" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it :

- load the table with a (hidden) field (for example a custom HTML attribute for the row) telling you the sort_index of the row, only if it isn't NULL
- order the table before in PHP, knowing that you will probably treat the NULL sort_order rows after the set ones
- on the drop event, access the rows before first :

  - get the highest non NULL row and set all those under (to your dropped one) to their respective order
  - now, if the following row isn't NULL increment the sort_order of all non-NULL ones under (you're shifting the table down one row)
  - same goes in the other case, if the row just over has a higher sort_order, decrement all those from the original row place to the final one (shifting up one row now)
- of course, set the dropped row to the right sort_order

This seems pretty complicated, and I believe in this kind of case you should define the table rows' sort_order as `NON NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` to get rid of that ugly NULL value.

Another way could be to create a custom SQL function `INSERT_ROW(index)` that does all the incrementing and decrementing. Doing this in Ajax just seems brutal.